# Error with including files

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, oop, class, import

I have a class structure

```
Class A
{
   Object of classB
   Object of classC
}
```

Now for this purpose I have files A.h/A.m B.h/B.m , C.h/C.m 
Now I have a separate file G.h which has  a number of global variables which are used by all the class A,B,C
Now I have imported B.h , C.h , G.h inside A.h . I also have separately imported the file G.h inside B.h and C.h

Now when build the project , I receive a link error for duplicate symbol on the global varibles (which is probably due to multiple inclusion of the file G.h) .

How can I solve this ??? The following is my code structure

```
//A.h

#import "B.h"
#import "C.h"
#import "G.h"

@interface A : NSObject {
  B *b;
  C *c;
}
//B.h
#import "G.h"

//C.h

#import "G.h"

//G.h
A *a=nil;
@interface G : NSObject { //whole class is empty}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should *declare* your globals in `G.h` but *define* them in `G.m`, so that they're only linked once in the target. So if, for example, you have a string constant that's globally defined, you would do:

**`G.h`**

```
extern NSString const *appName;
```

**`G.m`**

```
NSString const *appName = @"My Great App";
```

In your pasted code, it's the `A` instance that's being duplicated. It's imported into each other translation unit, but with the same name every time which means that the compiled objects can't be linked. Assuming you want a shared `A` instance called `a`, you'd do:

**`G.h`**

```
@class A;
extern A *a;
```

**`G.m`**

```
#import "A.h"
#import "G.h"

A *a = nil;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot .. did make a very fundamental mistake

Answer (score 0):

Use the `@class` compiler directive in your class headers instead of importing the headers of the other classes. `@class` provides a *forward declaration* of a given class, so you can defer importing its header until you really need it, which is usually going to be in the corresponding `.m` file.

So instead of something like this:

```
 #import "B.h"

 @interface A : NSObject
 {
     B someObj;
 }
```

...do this

```
 @class B;

 @interface A : NSObject
 {
     B someObj;
 }
```

Now the compiler will understand that `B` is the name of a class, and therefore allow you to use it as a data type without importing `B`'s header.